# Can Qt cut a line short, such that it not quit reaches the endpoint?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for a possibility to draw lines (with QPolygon, QLineF or something else) but to *set back from the end and start point* by certain distance. See the picture for an example

Is there already such a functionality somewhere in Qt?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be difficult to calculate the terminals of the line you actually want to draw using point vector addition.

```
void newTerminals(QPointF a, QPointF b, qreal gap, QPointF &aa, QPointF &bb)
{
    // Vector between points shortened to match gap
    QVector2D v(b.x() - a.x(), b.y() - a.y());
    v *= gap / v.length();

    // new start
    aa.rx() = a.x() + v.x();
    aa.ry() = a.y() + v.y();

    // new end
    bb.rx() = b.x() - v.x();
    bb.ry() = b.y() - v.y();
}
```

That should work. Instead of drawing line from `a` to `b`, draw the shortened line from `aa` to `bb`.

`// TODO: check for a != b, gap != 0, length > gap, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's builtin directly in Qt.
However you could actually create a bigger shape for your blocks by reimplementing the [shape()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) and/or the [boundingRect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect).
The paint function would still only draw the rectangle as you shown.

Then, you set the edges edges to start and end at the new augmented shape.